# Twitter Bootstrap typeahead with JSON

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap

How can i use Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead with JSON. My Bootstrap version is **2.2.1**

**My JSON response**

```
   [{"label":"Sistemski Administrator","value":"1"},{"label":"Jure Hotujec","value":"3"},{"label":" ","value":"4"},{"label":"Simona Jamnik","value":"5"},{"label":"Ma\u0161a Mu\u0161i\u010d","value":"6"},{"label":" ","value":"7"}]
```

All i've got now is this, but the source must be array and in my case it's JSON

```
$("#typeahead").autocomplete({
    soruce : soruce
});
```

Also i would like to use it with modal element, if that changes anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's parseJson method, then pass it in to typeahead's `source` parameter.

```
var jsonString =  '[{"label":"Sistemski Administrator","value":"1"},{"label":"Jure Hotujec","value":"3"},{"label":" ","value":"4"},{"label":"Simona Jamnik","value":"5"},{"label":"Ma\u0161a Mu\u0161i\u010d","value":"6"},{"label":" ","value":"7"}]';
var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
var sourceArr = [];

for (var i=0; i<jsonObj.length; i++) {
  sourceArr.push(jsonObj[i].label);
}

$("#typeahead").typeahead({
    source : sourceArr
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/4XZMb/1018/)
For more info, check out the [typeahead docs.](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead)

Comment: Wow thanks, is there any way that when i select a label, i get returned a value, like in callback or something.. thanks!

Comment: @user1141356 Yup. You can use the `updater` option, specified in the [docs.](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) Check out [this great tutorial](http://tatiyants.com/how-to-use-json-objects-with-twitter-bootstrap-typeahead/) on typeahead options.