# JSON output of a PDO statement to Twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pdo

I've just started querying databases using the PDO method and have hit a bit of a stumbling block.

What I'm trying to do: populate a typeahead field with the results of a simple query.

code to query database:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT `customers`.`Name` FROM `customers` WHERE       `customers`.`Name` LIKE :searchterm");

$searchterm = (isset($_POST['searchterm']) === true) ? $_POST['searchterm'] : '';

$query->bindValue(':searchterm', '%' . $searchterm . '%' );

$query->execute();

$rows=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo(json_encode($rows));
```

Javascript to populate typeahead:

```
            $('#customer-name').typeahead({
                source: function (query, process) {
                return $.post('ajax/get_customer_names.php', { searchterm: query }, function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                return process(data);
    });
}
});
```

Now I know that the typeahead expects an array of Strings in the following format

```
{
"one": "Singular sensation",
"two": "Beady little eyes",
"three": "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
}
```

the problem is that my code at the moment by sending to console.log outputs it in this format

```
[{"Name":"test"},{"Name":"Southern Testing"}]
```

I've been stuck on this problem all day and none of the examples I have found have been appropriate. I'm assuming I need to iterate through the  $rows variable and extract the string values but am not sure how to achieve that.
Can anybody let me know where I am going wrong and offer a solution?

Comment: Ok I've found a solution to the problem using the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687797/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-with-json however using this method the processing is done by the browser which is not ideal. Any solutions using server side processing?

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most elegant solution either, but I was stuck with the same problem and I solved it, server side, this way:

```
$rows=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $r){
  $array[] = $k['Name'];
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

This will format everything fine for typeahead to do it's thing.